# Ошибка 403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access / on this server

Tags: apache2

Изменен путь (`DocumentRoot`) для виртуального хоста вместо `/var/www/` на `/home/user/www/../..`,  которые созданы другим пользователем.  Изменен `envvars` на пользователя. Работает на Ubuntu 14.04.

Возникает ошибка при запуске:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

В стандартной директории работает правильно. Перепробовал множество вариантов, решения не нашел.